# How to create a bar graph with a csv file

Tags: javascript, php, csv

For my website I have to create a bar graph with the following data :
    90;
    99;
    87;
    78;
    89;
    67;
    85;
    67;
    85;
    100;

Those would be grades on 100 and I would like to put each one of them in a bar, next to each other. Do you know how I could do that with php (or javascript) ?

I have a picture for the bar of my graph registered under graphbar.png and my csv file is called websitedvpt.csv

I've looked for this everywhere but I really don't understand how it works, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

## **D3.js + C3.js**

A simple way to do this is using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) with [C3.js](http://c3js.org/). C3 is just a simple reusable patterns library for D3 begginners.

Generating a bar graph with the given data is as simple as:

HTML

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 90, 99, 87, 78, 89, 67, 85, 67, 85, 100]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VMqaz/)**

## **D3.js + NVD3.js**

[NVD3.js](http://nvd3.org/) is another D3.js collection of reusable charts like C3.js. 
Generating a bar graph with your data would be like this:

HTML

```
<div id='chart'>
  <svg style='height:500px'> </svg>
</div>
```

JS

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })    //Specify the data accessors.
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .staggerLabels(true)    //Too many bars and not enough room? Try staggering labels.
      .tooltips(false)        //Don't show tooltips
      .showValues(true)       //...instead, show the bar value right on top of each bar.
      .transitionDuration(350)
      ;

  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(exampleData())
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});

//Each bar represents a single discrete quantity.
function exampleData() {
 return  [ 
    {
      key: "Cumulative Return",
      values: [
        { 
          "label" : "A Label" ,
          "value" : 90
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "B Label" , 
          "value" : 99
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "C Label" , 
          "value" : 87
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "D Label" , 
          "value" : 78
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "E Label" ,
          "value" : 89
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "F Label" , 
          "value" : 67
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "G Label" , 
          "value" : 85
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "H Label" , 
          "value" : 67
        }, 
        { 
          "label" : "I Label" , 
          "value" : 85
        } , 
        { 
          "label" : "J Label" , 
          "value" : 100
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VMqaz/1/)**

## **jQuery Flot**

[jQuery.flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) is a simple graph library for jQuery that uses HTML Canvas.

This example would be plotted like this:

JS

```
var d1 = [[1,90], [2,99], [3,87], [4,78], [5,89], [6,67], [7,85], [8,67], [9,85], [10,100]];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [
        {
            data: d1,
            bars: {
                show: true
            }
        }
    ]);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

CSS

```
#placeholder {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VMqaz/2/)**

## **How to read CSV Data**

To read CSV data from a file you can use several libraries and depends on what languages you are using.

- For PHP, use [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php)
- For Ruby, use the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and its methods.
- For JavaScript (node.js) you can use the [CSV npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csv)
- For JavaScript (static) you can a library like [CSV.js](https://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use D3.JS to do this.. A full tutorial is here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 -- you can simply point it to a CSV file, then do your analytics/rendering against that as-needed. It will wind up generating an SVG and gives you the bits you need to do interactive stuff as well if you need it..

Sample code from same tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A seemingly good answer above, but svg can be a bit of a steep learning curve. You might well find it easier to use a combination of PHP and php's GD graphics library, which is a part of the php standard. That way, you just grab the data using fgetcsv - a very basic tutorial can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php - and then you are basically doing everything in the one language, which is the best way to get to grips with php or any other language.

And here's a very good, full-featured tute for GD:
http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/nasser20030219.php3?page=2

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that (see url)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart_c3_donut',
        data: {
          url: 'c3_donut.csv',
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected...this code is working well...

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="c3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'Date', 
        x_Format: '%Y-%m-%d', 
        url: 'dates.csv', 
    },
    axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries', 
    }
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
Date,Count
1996-12-20,1
1997-01-31,2
1997-01-31,3
1997-05-07,4
1997-10-03,5
1997-12-02,6
1997-12-02,7
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.